# How do I make a trigger that pushes a date forward incase of a row update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

So I'm trying to make a trigger that will push the lastBidDate forward by one day if there is a new bid placed. So I've made two tables and a trigger, however when I add something to the table, the trigger won't update anything. So I'm just wondering what is the problem with the trigger as I'm not getting any kinds of errors.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
itemNumber INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
startingPrice INT NOT NULL,
lastBidDate DATE,
acceptedBid INT,
PRIMARY KEY (itemNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Bid (
bidNumber INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
itemNumber INT NOT NULL,
bidderNumber INT NOT NULL,
bidDate DATE,
bid INT,
PRIMARY KEY (bidNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (itemNumber) REFERENCES item(itemNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (bidderNumber) REFERENCES bidder(bidderNumber)
);

INSERT INTO Item (name, startingPrice, lastBidDate, acceptedBid
) VALUES
 ('Item 1', 50, '2019-06-30', null),
 ('Item 2', 500, '2019-06-02', 800),
 ('Item 3', 1000, '2019-05-30', 1100),
 ('Item 4', 800, '2019-05-06', 800),
 ('Item 5', 200, '2019-07-31', null);
 

INSERT INTO Bid (itemNumber, bidderNumber, bidDate, bid) VALUES
 (1, 1, '2019-05-01', 500),
 (1, 2, '2019-05-01', 600),
 (1, 1, '2019-05-01', 700),
 (2, 5, '2019-05-01', 1000),
 (3, 3, '2018-05-02', 300),
 (3, 2, '2018-05-03', 400),
 (1, 3, '2018-05-06', 800),
 (2, 4, '2018-05-22', 1100);
```

And here is the trigger I made:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER moveEndDate AFTER INSERT ON Bid
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE Item JOIN Bid ON Item.itemNumber = Bid.itemNumber SET Item.LastBidDate = DATE_ADD(Item.LastBidDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE CURDATE() = Item.lastBidDate;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And to try it out I test with these INSERT commands.

```
INSERT INTO Item (name, startingPrice, lastBidDate, acceptedBid
) VALUES
 ('CustomItem', 50, '2021-05-12', null);

INSERT INTO Bid (itemNumber, bidderNumber, bidDate, bid) VALUES
 (6, 1, '2021-05-12', 500);
```

Comment: *Here are my tables* 1) Do not mix uppercase and lowercase (`CREATE TABLE Item` but `REFERENCES item(itemNumber)`). 2) Reference table not foung for `REFERENCES bidder(bidderNumber)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in using `Bid` in the row source of UPDATE statement. You must use scalar `NEW.itemNumber` value in additional WHERE condition instead.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER moveEndDate 
AFTER INSERT
ON Bid
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Item 
    SET Item.LastBidDate = Item.LastBidDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    WHERE CURRENT_DATE = Item.lastBidDate
      AND Item.itemNumber = NEW.itemNumber ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15ead2c8912a93ab2c46de25f817829c

PS. Lost reference to `bidder` table removed.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll make some tests but in advance I think you can not use the same table you made the trigger inside the trigger’s query